# How do I make a discord bot send certain images through a command?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

#client (my bot)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():

main_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
await main_channel.send('bot is ready')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'My Ping is {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

i want there to be a command like '!png dice' then it gives you a png of dice. I don't know if I have to make a list, where to put the list or if it gets the images from the web. this is my first time really coding a bot and I'm pretty new to coding as well. IF you are able to help can you simplify it so I could understand.

i was thinking of using this but it didn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def png(ctx)
await ctx.send(url of image)
```

but it didnt work. there is also no way that my code will know what image is wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one It would be like this

```
@client.command()
async def png(ctx):
    await ctx.send(url of image)
```

Also I would try to find an API that takes in a word and finds a photo. Pretty simple to find you could use https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis/bing-image-search-api. I think that is what your wanting.

Comment: when i put a url in, it says syntax error

Comment: is the url in a string? ex. `"url"`

Comment: the code is wrong: you're only passing in `ctx`. Rather, it should be `async def png(ctx, url : str):`